# find the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ (different $\theta$)

Tags: statistics

find the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$ (different $\theta$)

when $\theta=1$, $f(x;\theta)=1$ where $0<x<1$.
when $\theta=2$, $f(x;\theta)={1\over{2 \sqrt(x)}}$ where $0<x<1$.

i haven't met this situation before (two different theta). 
my guess is to generalise f(x;$\theta)$ into:
${1\over \theta}x^{{1\over \theta} -1}$

however, i dont think i can get the right answer

so please help me 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

One method would indeed be to generalize as you state. If interpreted that way (what should then be the range of $\theta$?) (you must check that that guess always gives a density, that is, always integrates to 1, and it does).  If you got only one observation from that density, find which value of $\theta$ maximizes the loglikelihood function, which is $$\log f(x;\theta)= \log(\frac1{\theta} x^{\frac1{\theta}-1})=-\log\theta + (\frac1{\theta}-1)\log x. $$  Differentiate this with respect to theta to get $$-\frac1{\theta}-\frac{\log x}{\theta^2}$$ and set that equal to zero. Solving that equation gives $\hat{\theta}=\log\frac1x$.

But, quite possible the intention was that there is only two possible densities, then just plug your observed $x$ into the two density functions given, and observe which gives the largest value. Chhosing the corresponding value of $\theta$ then gives the maximum likelihood estimator.